# sns line plot shows unnecessary output

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Trying to plot to cols from my data set.

Successfully plotted the values but it shows extra output apart from the plot ie (Text[] .... ) .

Here's the code :

```
dates = vac_plot['date'].apply(lambda x:np.array(x))
total = vac_plot['total_vaccinations'].apply(lambda x:np.array(x))
details = vac_plot[['date' ,  'total_vaccinations']]
here = sns.lineplot( x = dates , y= total, data = 'details')
ax.set_title('Total Vaccinations')
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='8'  
)
```

Here's the output :
[image: Output plot with extra unnecessary o/p the one with text[]]

Answer (score 3):

By default, Jupyter notebook would print the string representation of the last statement in the cell block. In this case, that is the return of the `plt.xticks()` function.

Just put `;` after `plt.xticks` to suppress the print out.

```
# other code...
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='8'  
);
```

Or you can add `plt.show()`:

```
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45, 
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='8'  
)

plt.show()
```

In the latter solution, `plt.show()` returns `None`, which Jupyter will not print out.